# Как преобразовать в char* из const string& и из const char*

Tags: c++, строки, классы, преобразование

У меня есть класс String.

Класс String выглядит так:

```
class String {
private: 
  char* string;
  size_t size;
public:
  String() {}
  String(const std::string&);
  String(const char*);
```

И в этом классе есть 2 конструктора.

- String (const string&);
- String (const char*);

Они должны записать полученные данные в переменную string в поле private.

Возможно ли вообще такое преобразование? Или стоит поменять реализацию класса?

(Такой класс дан по заданию)

Comment: Выделить память, скопировать. Обязательно дописать **глубокие** копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания! Или не морочить голову, и использовать нормальный `string` - С++ все же, не С...

Comment: ну так работы на пару строк. void init(const char* s, size_t len) {size=len; s = strdup(s);}  String(const char*s) { init(s, strlen(s));} String(const std::string&s) {init(s.c_str(); s.lengtg();}` если только не промазал в буковках. можно было бы и ещё меньше кода, но было бы не так эффективно. правда там ещё на nullptr в init проверить желательно, но это такое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как отметил @KoVadim, можно воспользоваться **strdup()**, но стоит обратить внимание на то, что **strdup()** не соответствует ANSI C из-за чего некоторые компиляторы отказываются его использовать, склоняясь к использованию **_strdup()**.

Для конвертации типов можно воспользоваться const_cast или старым сишным приведением.

```
char* foo(const char* ch) {
    return const_cast<char*>(ch);
}
```

или

```
char* foo(const char* ch) {
    return (char*)ch;
}
```

Таким образом можно привести и std::string к char* с помощью метода c_str().

```
int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    char* ch1;
    char* ch;

    std::string str = "std::string text";
    const char* c_ch = "const char text";

    ch1 = foo(str.c_str());
    ch = foo(c_ch);

    std::cout << ch1 << "\n";
    std::cout << ch;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

std::string text

const char text

Comment: с strdup все сильно сложнее. Она начиная ещё с с89 в статусе "надо включить", но как то страшно. Но вроде дело наконец то сдвинулось с мертвой точки - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2353.htm   _strdup - это какой то страшный костыль:)

Comment: в функции `foo` нужно делать копирование **строки**, а не указателя. То-есть  `strlen` , `malloc`, `memcpy`